# R Shiny writing data to google sheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny

I have problem where my Submit button won't write data to googlesheets. It will work if I run it as normal data (outside of reactive) but I think it needs to be reactive so I can change values and it will append values to the sheets. So I have a bug somewhere. How it should work is that everytime I press Submit button, it should write / append those input values to googlesheets. It opens the page correctly and UI looks correct, but just nothing happens when I press Submit button.

Here is example I'm trying to follow: https://www.jdtrat.com/blog/connect-shiny-google/
This example I get running just fine, so no problem on that.

IN the exmpale linked it is shown how to connect to googlesheets. But you need to create connection and then have sheet_id and sheet named. I have googlesheet "GOLF" and it only has 1 sheet named "shots"

```
options(
  gargle_oauth_email = TRUE,
  gargle_oauth_cache = "your-app-folder-name/.secrets"
)

sheet_id <- drive_get("GOLF")$id
```

Calling Modules

```
    ui <-  navbarPage("TESTING",
                      tabPanel("GOLF", test_ui(id = "module_0")))
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
      test_server(id = "module_0")
      
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

ModuleUI

```
test_ui <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  sideBar <- list(
    dateInput(inputId = ns("date"), label = "Date", value = as.Date(Sys.Date())),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("course"), label =  "Course", choices = c("PGH: Vanha Peura", "PGH: Porkkala"), multiple = F),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("hole"), label =  "Hole", choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"), multiple = F),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("shot"), label =  "Shot", choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), multiple = F),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("club"), label = "Club", choices = c("D", "W3", "H3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "PW", "52", "56", "60", "P")),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("lie"), label = "Ball Lie", choices = c("Fairway", "Rough", "Sand", "Recovery", "Fringe", "Green")),
    actionButton("location", "Get Location"),
    textInput(inputId = ns("lat"), label = "Latitude", value = ""),
    textInput(inputId = ns("lon"), label = "Longitude", value = ""),
    sliderInput(inputId = ns("putt_length"), label = "Putt Distance", min = 1, max = 30, value = 5, step = 1),
    actionButton(inputId = "save", label = "Submit")
    
  )
  
  page_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(sideBar)
  )
  
}
```

Module Server

```
test_server <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {

      response_data <- reactive({
        response_data <- tibble::tibble(Date = input$date,
                                        Course = input$course,
                                        Hole = input$hole,
                                        Shot = input$shot,
                                        Club = input$club,
                                        Lie = input$lie,
                                        Latitude = input$lat,
                                        Longitude = input$lon,
                                        Putt_distance = input$putt_length)
        response_data
        
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$save, {
        
        values <- read_sheet(ss = sheet_id,
                             sheet = "shots")
        
        if (nrow(values) == 0) {
          sheet_write(data = response_data(),
                      ss = sheet_id,
                      sheet = "shots")
        } else {
          sheet_append(data = response_data(),
                       ss = sheet_id,
                       sheet = "shots")
        }
      }
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Where is "shots" defined and sheet_id defined for "shots"?

Comment: I added default connection to googlesheets, I think in the example link they explain it, but "shots" is just my googlesheet name. I probably should add how to create and name a sheet in googlesheets on top of this, but as connection is not the problem in my view I left it out and as everyone has different logins as well.

Comment: googlesheets4::gs4_create(name = "GOLF", 
           # Create a sheet called main for all data to 
           # go to the same place
           sheets = "shots")

Comment: As you are using modules, you may have a namespace issue with sheet_id.

Comment: Aah, that must be the case, I made it without modules and works nicely. Need to figure out how to get it working with modules. Thanks